# WordPress Custom Post Types on Custom Categories

Tags: php, wordpress

Can some one let me know how I can create custom Category and Post type including the items in side the red box and add them to WordPress dashboard?

[image]

Comment: RTFM: [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Comment: Thanks Joseph but how about Categories? How can I Create them? besides how Can I add them to dashboard?

Comment: Use [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) to add a custom category. It'll automatically show up in the dashboard.

Comment: Multi-post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/83361 Please, read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Long explanation**

Below an example code:

```
add_action('init', 'demo_register_post_type');

function demo_register_post_type() {
register_post_type('demo', array(
'labels' => array(
'name' => 'Demos',
'singular_name' => 'Demo',
'add_new' => 'Add new demo',
'edit_item' => 'Edit demo',
'new_item' => 'New demo',
'view_item' => 'View demo',
'search_items' => 'Search demos',
'not_found' => 'No demos found',
'not_found_in_trash' => 'No demos found in Trash'
),
'public' => true,
'supports' => array(
'title',
'excerpt'
),
'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
));
}
```

And for the categories:

```
add_action('init', 'demo_add_default_boxes');

function demo_add_default_boxes() {
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'demo');
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'demo');
}
```

Of course, you can customize it, instead of "demo" having something else.

---

**Short explanation**

You need to add **'taxonomies' => array('category')** in your register_post_type() function.

- [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)
- [register_taxonomy()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)
- [register_taxonomy_for_object_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type)

Let us know please.

Comment: Thanks, oh my god you have a nice hard Name!:-) .this is exactly what I was looking for.Now can you please let me know how I can display the created demos based on their categories on a page.For Example let say I have a page called "Art" and I would like to display ONLY demos how has categorized under "artCat" category? Once again Thanks

Comment: $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'demo', 
    'cat' => 5, // or whatever is the "id" for "artCat"
    'posts_per_page' => 10
) );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); // etc...

Comment: Let me make my question a little more clear! well I have already created some Custom Page Templates now my question is, Is it possible to call those Custom Page Templates at Category creation page therefore ech template will associate with it's own category?

Comment: each template will be associated with it's own category, also you can display content from more categories on custom page template

Comment: Ok so you are telling that I have to use the above code $loop= new WP_Query on each diffrent tempate based on id of demo and cat? am I right?

Comment: if the id's and cat slug is different on each template, then yes, otherwise i would use the same template for each page

Answer (score 2):

To register a new custom post type, use the [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function.

To add a custom category, use the [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function.

Once you add these, they'll automatically show up in your dashboard.

Comment: Perfect , thanks just one final question, how can I put them under one section like having "Products" (grey header) here?

Comment: @Behseini - Agian, this happens automatically. That custom post type is named **Products**, so it shows up like that. The same will happen with your custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

To show a custom category you added with [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function you should set "show_admin_column" parameter to **true** (it's false by default)

eg.

```
register_taxonomy('event_category', array('event'), array(
  'public' => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'show_admin_column' => true
));
```